# Quartzite job scheduling in Clojure web application

Tags: web-applications, clojure, scheduled-tasks

I need to execute a function in Clojure web application periodically every day at given time. I tried the Quartzite library but it did't go well. I put the Quartzite code into an init function, that is called after application deployment but the scheduled job did not execute. When I tried different scheduling (ie. every 200 milliseconds) the job executed few times at the beginning and then it stops.

I am probably doing something obviously wrong but I can't see it. Can someone help me with this?

I am using the Luminus framework. The code is as follows:

```
(j/defjob import-logs [ctx]
  (print "something")
)

(defn init
  "init will be called once when
   app is deployed as a servlet on
   an app server such as Tomcat
   put any initialization code here"
  []

  (qs/initialize)
  (qs/start)
  (let [job (j/build
              (j/of-type import-logs)
              (j/with-identity (j/key "jobs.import.1")))
        trigger (t/build
                 (t/with-identity (t/key "triggers.1"))
                 (t/start-now)
                 (t/with-schedule (schedule
                                     (with-repeat-count 10)
                                     (with-interval-in-milliseconds 1000)
                                   )))]
    (qs/schedule job trigger)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize it correctly. You have to create an instance of scheduler and pass it to `qs/schedule` function

```
(defn init
  "init will be called once when
   app is deployed as a servlet on
   an app server such as Tomcat
   put any initialization code here"
  []
  (let [s (qs/start (qs/initialize))
        job (j/build
             (j/of-type import-logs)
             (j/with-identity (j/key "jobs.import.1")))
        trigger (t/build
                 (t/with-identity (t/key "triggers.1"))
                 (t/start-now)
                 (t/with-schedule (schedule
                                   (with-repeat-count 10)
                                   (with-interval-in-milliseconds 1000)
                                   )))]
    (qs/schedule s job trigger)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Luminus as a base, you could use [immutant's scheduling](http://immutant.org/documentation/current/jobs.html#sec-2).

Scheduling is integrated behind the scene, and here's the quickest way to use it:

```
 (ns your.ns
    (:require [immutant.jobs :as jobs]))

 (jobs/schedule :my-at-job-name  
           #(println "I fire 4 times with a 10ms delay between each, starting in 500ms.")
           :in 500   ; ms
           :every 10 ; ms
           :repeat 3
           :singleton false)
```

Comment: It was not integrated in my version of Luminus but it did the job. It is weird thought, because both libraries are build on top of Quartz. But I like Immutant more, it is much simpler. Thanks for your answer.